# Inline Installation of Chrome Extension is Not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have develop a simple extension for chrome and I want that people can install it from my website as well, So I have a page with a button on which if visitor will click, the extension will prompt, asking user to add it to there browser. But the problem is it is only prompt on my computer. It is not working on other computer. I mean if I open the same page on different computer to install the extension nothing is happen. Below is the link of my extension page.

http://www.custom-search.com/test.html

I have verified the website in webmaster tool as well. Any help will works, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I get the prompt in Chrome 52. Also, a username containing "seo" is unlikely to help with goodwill.

Comment: @DanDascalescu I am just a practicing to develop chrome extension, it is nothing like I am spreading spam over internet. After all it is just a simple google custom search api and I don't have much control on it.

Comment: Not repro at my end

Comment: that is what I am saying. can you figure out the problem.

Comment: I tried to installed your custom search extention and I successfully installed it. Im using Chrome browser version 52.0.2743.116. Have you check your console? Are you using version 52?

Comment: Yes I am using version 52. Actually I am able to install it on my computer....but not able to install any other computer...don't know what is the problem...I will figure it out...Thank you anyway @d.datul1990 .

Comment: Hi seoakashmishra, did you solved your issue?